# Replace a column with strings from another reference file

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to use a match criteria, then go 2 lines below the match and replace part of that line with several strings located in another reference file and save each as separate outputs with names identical to . Below is the reference, main and output files [names in the brackets]:

```
[main]
This week's menu:
Main dish: xxx
Side: yyy

[ref]
Day1 Chicken Salad
Day2 Beef Yogurt
Day3 Pork Fruit

[output1 : Day1]
This week's menu:
Main dish: Chicken
Side: Salad

[output2 : Day2]
This week's menu:
Main dish: Beef
Side: Yogurt

etc.
```

Here is my code that is not working and I am stuck. Can you please help?

```
awk -v fname=$1 dish=$2 side=$3 '/menu/ {getline}{$3=dish} {getline;getline;}{$2=side}1' main ref > fname
```

Comment: One of the issues: You are using the awk variable `fname` outside of the awk script (in the calling shell's environment, where it doesn't exist). Also, if you are using shell redirection, you can only dump all of awk's output into one file. To selectively write into different files, use `>` inside the awk script.

Comment: Is main file etched in stone or you allowed to alter it?

Comment: main file can be altered but has to be saved as a new output file named according to the 1st columns of ref file.

Comment: [edit] your question to show separate the blocks of text, don't show everything as a single code block and make sure the expected output you show is **exactly** the output you expect from the input you show (no `etc.` for example) so we can copy/paste it to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `gsub` to replace the strings "xxx" and "yyy". Read the `main` file into a variable, then iterate over the `ref` file's lines. For each line, prepare the variable's content by replacing the strings accordingly, then print it into the corresponding output file.

```bash
awk -v m="$(< main)" '{s=m; gsub("xxx",$2,s); gsub("yyy",$3,s); print s > $1}' ref
```

---

> is it possible to point to the columns instead of "xxx" and "yyy" ?

This is a little bit more complicated. The following approach reads in the `main` file linewise into an array, then iterates over the `ref` file like above. For each line in the latter file, it now iterates over the array, replacing certain columns in certain rows using `if`.

```bash
awk '
  NR == FNR { i+=1; m[i]=$0 }
  NR > FNR  { fname=$1; dish=$2; side=$3
    for (i in m) { $0=m[i]
      if (i==2) $3=dish
      if (i==3) $2=side
      print > fname
    }
  }
' main ref
```

---

Both approaches were tested on GNU Awk 5.2.2 / Linux 6.3.3, and produced the following files:

`Day1`

```
This week's menu:
Main dish: Chicken
Side: Salad
```

`Day2`

```
This week's menu:
Main dish: Beef
Side: Yogurt
```

`Day3`

```
This week's menu:
Main dish: Pork
Side: Fruit
```

Comment: for gsub, is it possible to point to the columns instead of "xxx" and "yyy" ? these are arbitrary strings and could change

Comment: got an error --> awk: file "": line 1: Newline in string  Context is:
>>>     This week's menu:
>>>             <<<

Comment: @EverLearner This approach reads `main` into a variable at once, then only iterates over `ref`. Thus, referring to columns via `$2` etc. only works for `ref` (cf. `gsub(…,$2,…)` etc.). The value of `m` (the contents of the `main` file) is a multi-line string, so columns don't make direct sense there. I have added another approach which reads `main` into an array, then iterates over it, writing each line back to `$0`, so you can reference the columns. Also, the "Newline in string" error might be due to different implementations of awk. This approach was tested on GNU Awk 5.2.2 / Linux 6.3.3.

Comment: note that for non-gawk, `for (i in m)` is not guaranteed to be ordered

Comment: @jhnc Ah, thank you, good to know. Using `for (i=1; i<=length(m); i++)` instead would be the (more) universal way to go, then.

Comment: yes, some kind of for loop. maybe `for (j=1; j<=i; j++)` since `i` already stores precalculated `length(m)`

Comment: @pmf - I tested the second script on MKS KornShell but the lines in output files are written backwards. ` Day1 ->
Side: Salad
Main dish: Chicken
This week's menu: `
Any resolution?

Comment: @EverLearner Try changing `for (i in m)` to what was suggested by @jhnc or me in the comments above.

Comment: I changed the for loop syntax but it is still reversed

Comment: I even tried for (i=length(m); i>=1; i--), but no luck!

Comment: Regarding "Using `for (i=1; i<=length(m); i++)` instead would be the (more) universal way to go, then." - per the POSIX awk spec `length()` only operates on strings, not arrays, so YMMV using it on an array, it's definitely not universal. `for (i=1; i in m; i++)` would be universal as long as there are no gaps in in the indices of `m`. Even for gawk, `for (i in m)` is not guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: Also, YMMV using `print > fname` without closing the output files that's creating. Depending on how many you create you could run into a "too many open files" error with most awks or a slow-down with gawk.